# Missing artifact after updating to the latest version

Tags: java, maven, github, version

I'm using a Github repository using Jitpack:

```
<repository>
  <id>jitpack.io</id>
  <url>https://jitpack.io/</url>
</repository>
```

and

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.bys1</groupId>
  <artifactId>importer</artifactId>
  <version>0.3.1-Beta</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Repo link: https://github.com/bys1/importer/releases/tag/0.3.1-Beta

After updating from version `0.3-Beta` to `0.3.1-Beta`, I got a "missing artifact" error. When checking the `.m2/repository/com/github/bys1/importer/0.3.1-Beta` folder I only found 2 .lastUpdated files.

When changing back to `0.3-Beta` everything works fine.
I've also tried using the commit id as version; didn't work, same error.

I have tried searching on Google to fix it. I found several people having the same issue. None of the solutions worked.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This means the artifacts has been removed or is not being offered anymore..

Comment: @khmarbaise it's my own repo...

Comment: @khmarbaise https://github.com/bys1/importer/releases/tag/0.3.1-Beta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a maven build error for version 0.3.1-beta. You can view the build error log at - https://jitpack.io/com/github/bys1/importer/0.3.1-Beta/build.log

Should work after the build error is fixed.